# Set default value for date selector in phoenix framework to current date

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the app I'm developing I have a date selector which will mostly be used with the current date as value (or a date a few days later). In order to reduce work for my users, I want to set today's date as default value.

I can easily set the year  with:
`date_select f, :date, class="form_control", year: [options: @current_year, @current_year+1]`,
but have not managed to do something similar for the month and day.

I've tried changing the code to `date_select f, :date, class="form_control", year: [options: @current_year, @current_year+1], month: [default: 2]`,
`date_select f, :date, class="form_control", year: [options: @current_year, @current_year+1], month: [default: "2"]`,
`date_select f, :date, class="form_control", year: [options: @current_year, @current_year+1], month: [default: "02"]`,
but none of these worked. Replacing `default` with `value` made no difference. What mistake am I making?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the docs, the default option is given directly to date_select. So this should work:

```
date_select f, :date, default: {@current_year, 2, 13}
```

You can pass the date using other formats too, like a map instead of a tuple. [Check datetime_select docs for the accepted formats](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#datetime_select/3).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if anyone is wondering you can also set the default time by doing this

```
<%= datetime_select f, :start, class: "form-control", 
default: {{@current_year, @current_month, @current_day}, 
{@current_hour, @current_minute, @current_second}} %>
```